# Formatting Output of Itertools.Products

Tags: python

I'm new to python and coding (last night). I need to generate a very large number of itertools products with a specific format for the output. I can generate the combinations using,

```
import itertools
s=[ ['CPT1','OTHERCPT1','OTHERCPT2','OTHERCPT3','OTHERCPT4','OTHERCPT5','OTHERCPT6','OTHERCPT7','OTHERCPT8','OTHERCPT9','OTHERCPT10','CONCURR1','CONCURR2','CONCURR3','CONCURR4','CONCURR5','CONCURR6','CONCURR7','CONCURR8','CONCURR9','CONCURR10'], ['15756','15757','15758','43496','49006','20969','20955','20956','20957','20962','20970','20972','20973'],['CPT1','OTHERCPT1','OTHERCPT2','OTHERCPT3','OTHERCPT4','OTHERCPT5','OTHERCPT6','OTHERCPT7','OTHERCPT8','OTHERCPT9','OTHERCPT10','CONCURR1','CONCURR2','CONCURR3','CONCURR4','CONCURR5','CONCURR6','CONCURR7','CONCURR8','CONCURR9','CONCURR10'], ['15756','15757','15758','43496','49006','20969','20955','20956','20957','20962','20970','20972','20973']]
x=list(itertools.product(*s))
print x
```

however the output appears as such:

```
('CPT1', '15756', 'CPT1', '15756'), ... etc.
```

I would like it to appear:

```
SELECT IF(CPT1='15756' AND CPT1='15756').
SELECT IF(...).
etc.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So write the code to construct some strings with `.format` that are formatted the way you want... SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: I will try to work with this. Not trying to have anyone do my work for me but have zero knowledge base. Sorry.

Comment: There are many great online resources for learning python. Jump in and educate yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use string formatting (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

```
import itertools
s = [[...first list...],[...second list...]]
for p in itertools.product(*s):
    print("SELECT IF(CPT1='{}' AND CPT1='{}').".format(*p))
```